# Django filter parent where ALL child values meet criteria

Tags: django, django-queryset

Based on these models:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Task(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey('Job', related_name='tasks')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I need a query that returns each Job where `Job.status` is null and **ALL** child `Task.status`'s are "COMPLETE".

For context, when all `Task.status`'s are complete, a comparison between values in each sibling `Task` will occur, it should not be carried out until all siblings `Task` is set to "COMPLETE", so the query will return those that are complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can work with an `Exists` subquery:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Q

Job.objects.filter(
    ~Exists(
        Task.objects.filter(~Q(status='COMPLETE'), job_id=OuterRef('pk'))
    ),
    status=None
)
```

This will result in a query that looks like:

```
SELECT app_name_job.*
FROM app_name_job
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT U0.id, U0.job_id, U0.status
  FROM app_name_task U0
  WHERE NOT U0.status = COMPLETE
    AND U0.job_id = app_name_job.id
  )
  AND app_name_job.status IS NULL)
```

prior to [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0), you will first need to annotate, and then filter:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Q

Job.objects.annotate(
    all_complete=~Exists(
        Task.objects.filter(~Q(status='COMPLETE'), job_id=OuterRef('pk'))
    )
).filter(all_complete=True, status=None)
```

If a `Job` does not have any tasks, then *all* the tasks (well there are none) are considered complete, so such `Job`s are also listed in the result if the `status` is `None`.

Comment: Yes, this did the job perfectly. I tried to get the solution myself but I just don't have much experience with queries. Thank you.

Comment: this is my query Invoice.objects.annotate(all_paid=Exists(InvoiceAmount.objects.filter(is_paid=True, id=OuterRef('pk')))).filter(all_paid=True)

what am i doing wrong? tried this same. i want to get all invoices where invoiceamount object is paid

Comment: @AbdulRaffay: you annotate if there is at least one that is paid, not that these are all paid.

Comment: i want to get invoices even if one invoice amount of that invoice is paid

Comment: @AbdulRaffay: it is probably better to ask a new question with the models and sample data, and explain what exactly you aim to achieve.

Comment: yes sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76778126/django-filter-parent-on-base-of-child