# Django filter parent on base of child

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i have invoice model

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    name                         = models.ForeignKey('Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

i have another invoice amount model which have FK of invoice

```
class InvoiceAmount(models.Model):
    invoice                         = models.ForeignKey('Invoice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount                          = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_paid                         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

i want to get invoices which have is_paid = True invoice amounts

i am using this query but it's not working

```
Invoice.objects.annotate(all_paid=Exists(InvoiceAmount.objects.filter(is_paid=True, id=OuterRef('pk')))).filter(all_paid=True)
```

Comment: Why is there an `InvoiceAmount` model? It seems like this is a on-to-one relation: you have one `InvoiceAmount` *per* `Invoice`, so then it makes more sense to just store the amount and payment status in the `Invoice` itself.

Comment: because there can be multiple invoice amounts for one invoice. for example if someone wants to buy something on installments then we will have multiple invoiceamounts for that invoice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there are no `InvoiceAmount`s with `is_paid=False`, so:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Q

Invoice.objects.annotate(
    all_paid=~Exists(
        InvoiceAmount.objects.filter(~Q(is_paid=True), invoice_id=OuterRef('pk'))
    )
).filter(all_paid=True)
```